# How get value from inner a xmltag?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

I get a list as `XmlNodeList` from xml document. I can get innertext values using `GetElementsByTagName`. But I need read value from inner a tag. Want to read just  "USD" in "Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD"" part.

```
<Currency CrossOrder="0" 
          Kod="USD" 
          CurrencyCode="USD">
    <Unit>1</Unit>
    <Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim>
    <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
    <ForexBuying>4.0707</ForexBuying>
    <ForexSelling>4.0780</ForexSelling>
    <BanknoteBuying>4.0678</BanknoteBuying>
    <BanknoteSelling>4.0841</BanknoteSelling>
    <CrossRateUSD />
    <CrossRateOther />
</Currency>
<Currency CrossOrder="1" 
          Kod="AUD" 
          CurrencyCode="AUD">
    <Unit>1</Unit>
    <Isim>AVUSTRALYA DOLARI</Isim>
    <CurrencyName>AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR</CurrencyName>
    <ForexBuying>3.1389</ForexBuying>
    <ForexSelling>3.1594</ForexSelling>
    <BanknoteBuying>3.1245</BanknoteBuying>
    <BanknoteSelling>3.1784</BanknoteSelling>
    <CrossRateUSD>1.2938</CrossRateUSD>
    <CrossRateOther />
</Currency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `XmlReader`, `<Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD">` is a node of `Element` type.

`CurrencyCode` is an attribute in this node.
If you want to get "USD", you are getting the value of `CurrencyCode` attribute.

Try `XmlReader.GetAttribute` method.

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.getattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2#definition).